# Would using thunderbolt-to-hdmi help?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, resolution

Late 2013 Macbook Pro 15.4" 2.6Ghz

I connect HDMI and not always do the full spectrum of resolutions appear within the list of choices?

`System Preferences (app) -> Displays (preference icon) -> Display (tab) -> Scaled (tab)`

What would cause this?

Monitor is more of a TV I guess: Seiki 4K 39-inch.

Even if 4k would perhaps cause a problem, 1080p, 1080i, and even 1440x900 failed to appear a good portion of the time.

Is this perhaps a hardware issue with the MBP's HDMI port?

Would it help if I used the thunderbolt-to-HDMI cable instead? Perhaps because of a faulty HDMI port maybe?

Comment: Don't use scaled.

Answer (score 1):

## Option+click `Scaled`

You can toggle between Apple’s easy-to-understand “Larger Text”–“More Space” icons mode and the other mode listing specific resolutions. To toggle, hold down the Option key while clicking `Scaled` radio button.

[image]

[image]

## Retina

As for that comment “Don’t used scaled.” on the Question, that is wrong advice. Scaled options are [Retina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retina_Display)-style by default, more commonly known as [`HiDPI`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density). Note the checkbox `Show low resolution modes` in the second screen shot above. Checking that box and choosing a resolution listed with the notation `(low resolution)` means you are disabling the Retina feature and scaling up the image crudely (wasting pixels).